# How to play Facebook videos without Adobe Flash player using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, flash

I'm using Fedora 21 and using Mozilla Firefox, the latest version.

When I had Adobe Flash (flash-plugin) installed, my Computer was freezed at least 4 times in a day, and Gnome shell crashed a lot.

I suspected Adobe flash, and indeed, since I removed it, no single crash and freeze so far (2 weeks).

I very like the Youtube HTML5 player, and I wonder if there is any way to play Facebook videos in HTML5, or something similar.

Any extention or modify.

I believe that the solution isn't depends the operating system, so if you have a solution for Windows, I would like to hear.

I would be really glad to get helped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the game is Flash-based then, no, you will need to have Flash player installed. Can you install Chrome as that has a different Flash player built-in...

Comment: That is a real shame, that such a company still asks for plugins. Hope they will not ask for Java next year.

Answer (score 8):

I have not personally tested the following suggestions. You should be able to add the m prefix before the URL, which would allow you to view the video without flash.

[Example: m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com)

The following Firefox extension might also do the job, **I have not tested this**.

[Video Without Flash Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-without-flash/)

Comment: The `m` prefix really does work. is there any way to make it automatically??

Comment: I have tested a few GreaseMonkey scripts and Firefox extensions to no avail. If you would like, we could go over some of the issues you had with Adobe Flash. The only other suggestion I can currently think of is using Google Chrome which has Adobe Flash built in.